# Formatting a bullet list when text wrapped next to an image

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word-2007, text-formatting

I can't find any combination of list formatting and default or custom text-wrap settings where, for item 4, the second line of text lines up correctly - i.e. where the 'n' lines up with the 'S' as expected (see screenshot below).

How can I make the second and further lines of a list item  line up correctly when to the right of an image?  The document displayed has the following characteristics.

- The list item styles are the Word 2007 default settings
- When the image is removed the list item text lines up correctly
- The image text-wrap formatting is set to 'square'

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the indentation sliders on the ruler to solve the problem. If the ruler is not displayed, you can make is visible though the <kbd>View</kbd> menu: <kbd>View > Ruler</kbd>

Note in the following figure where the left-indent slider is located when I select the bulleted item, which is not aligned as per your requirements. The left-indent slider is the lower one; it is highlighted with the red arrow.

[image: before moving the slider]

However, when I select the rest of the bulleted items and move the left-indent slider, as shown below, the text is aligned as per your requirements.

[image: after moving the slider]

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/adjust-the-indent-in-a-bulleted-or-numbered-list-HP005192551.aspx) is some documentation that may give further directions.

Comment: Wow - so much for discoverability.  I'd never have found that on my own.  I'd been thinking I'd have to resort to a kludge, such as inserting the image and the text into a 1x2 table to make it work.  Thank you so much!