# Formatting a bullet list (in Outlook)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, format, list

This question is based on [Formatting a bullet list when text wrapped next to an image](https://superuser.com/q/552241/53590).

How would you do that same thing in Outlook?

Comment: Are you really expecting us to go and follow the link you're citing ? It would make it easier for us (those who potentially will answer your quesiton) if you copy the relevant part into your post :)

Comment: I would have but the original has pictures (which I couldn't copy) and several comments.  It felt wrong to copy the whole thing.  I also tried to add a comment to the original question but that didn't work either because only answers are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps shown from your article in Word.  Then copy it to Outlook would be the easiest solution.

Comment: I didn't do exactly that but by going thu the process I found the solution.  Thanks bunches.